# textarea tabulado, ¿cómo eliminar tabulación?

Tags: css, html5

[image: textarea tabulado]

el textarea aparece con un tabulado automático, ¿como eliminarlo?

https://codepen.io/andres3dmd/pen/mjRjWZ

Comment: añade el código con el que trabajas

Comment: He mirado tu código y el problema lo tienes en la definición del **textarea**. Al final del mismo tienes espacios y tabuladores, lo que hace que te salgan siempre por considerar que es parte de su contenido. Limpia esos espacios (o tabulación) y problema resuelto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes esos "espacios" o "tabulaciones" añadidos en tu código:

```
<textarea class="form-control">                 <-- Aquí tienes tabuladores
</textarea>
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <label>
    <i class="fa fa-asterisk requerid"></i>
    Observaciones
  </label>
  
  <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```